# Elixir anonymous function application in list tail returns arithmetic error

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, elixir

I'm pretty new to elixir and functional programming in general and I am having a map of the form:

```
key => [int, int]
```

for example:

```
14 => [1,0]
```

Using the snippet below, I have managed to increase the value of 1 in [1,0] by 1 but I don't manage to do the same for the second value, aka '0'.

This is my working sample code for the head of the list

```
iex(2)> a = Map.update!(a, 'b', fn([a|b]) -> [a+1] ++ b end)
```

This is my code and the error I get for the second element of the list, please note that my list is only consisting of 2 elements and this is not going to change

```
iex(3)> a = Map.update!(a, 'b', fn([a|b]) -> a ++ [b+1] end) 
** (ArithmeticError) bad argument in arithmetic expression
    :erlang.+([0], 1)
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:228: :erl_eval.expr/5
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:470: :erl_eval.expr/5
    (elixir) lib/map.ex:727: Map.update!/3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the second case when you match on `[a|b] = [1,0]`, `a` will be an integer (1) and `b` will be a list ([0]). In order to increase `b` with that function, all you'd have to do update your matching part and how you handle a and b:

```
a = Map.update!(a, 'b', fn([a,b]) -> [a] ++ [b+1] end)
```

Alternatively you can also do

```
a = Map.update!(a, 'b', fn([a,b]) -> [a, b+1] end)
```

To construct the updated list.

Comment: After this function, what I want to have is key => [value1, value2] where values are increased by 1 but they are still a single list and not list of lists

Comment: So before update your value is [1,0] and after update you'd like it to be [2,1] ? In that case you change the above function to `fn([a,b]) -> [a + 1, b + 1] end` BTW Why would you need a list of lists there?

Comment: Oh thanks, is working as expectedly sorry for my previous comment

Comment: Sure no worries

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update all keys of the map, use `Enum.map` like this:

```
the_map
|> Enum.map(fn {k, [v1, v2]} -> {k, [v1+1, v2+1]} end)
|> Enum.into(%{})
```

Note that `Enum.map` will return a list (keyword list in this case), so you need to put data back into a map.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the tail of the list is a list:

```
iex(2)> [h | t] = [1, 0]
[1, 0]
iex(3)> h
1
iex(4)> t
[0]
```

When you take a look on your error description, `:erlang.+([0], 1)` it shows that you want to add `[0]` to `1`.

If you want to pattern match the list with exactly two elements, you may do:

```
fn([a, b]) -> [a + 1, b + 1] end
```

However, in such cases it would be better to use tuples.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, appreciated!